# Access external IP address from service

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to get the external IP address for a POD? It doesn't appear to be populating in the environmental variables for a service, so I was wondering if there was another way to get that information.

Basically: I'm setting up a proftpd service, and it needs to send out its external ip as well as a port for passive communication. Right now, it's sending the local IP address which is causing FTP clients to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kubernetes service discovery mechanism (DNS or environment variable) doesn't populate the external IP.

One way to work around is to create a static IP first, then assign it to your [service](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L2093-L2098).

Or you can exec kubectl inside your cluster to get the external IP but that's nasty.